Example of a simple transparent indexed annuity?
I am working on a University project where I need to provide a 2-page overview of

An indexed annuity, which uses zero coupon bonds and options; the underlying of the options are a broad market index.

I need to find a real-life example of such a product. Does anyone know any real-life examples I could use? I've looked at the documentation of e.g.:
https://www.allianzlife.com/what-we-offer/annuities/fixed-index-annuities/Accumulation-Advantage-7
but I can't find a clear breakdown of what they do with your money. For example, I don't know if they buy zero coupon bonds or another type of government bond. Do you know of any real-life products that clearly show the bonds and options they buy to provide you with an indexed annuity?

(unfortunately they usually don't want to give out the exact details because then the competitors can figure out the profit margin and/or duplicate the product).
